# How can I travel along an elliptical path over time and continue to loop indefinitely?

Tags: javascript, math, animation, geometry, kinematics

The equation of an elliptical path can be defined as:

[image: x^2 / (240/2)^2 + y^2 / (h/2)^2 = 1]

Where **h** = a randomly generated height between 10 and 60.

And **t** = time in seconds elapsed.

How can I start at a specific point when **t = 0**, and follow along the path as **t** increases, looping indefinitely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually easier than that. Position on an elliptical path over time is:

```
x = Math.cos(t)*w/2
y = Math.sin(t)*h/2
```

With `w` and `h` the width and height, respectively. Scale `t` as needed to get the speed you want.